# MVC 4 drop down box error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have had this error for over a day now and I really can't seem to fix it. I know there are a lot of questions on this topic online which I have read over and over and still haven't solved the issue.
I'm just learning MVC 4 so I'm extremely confused.
I get the error message:

The ViewData item that has the key 'cabinCrewId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

My Controller:

```
 public ActionResult AddCrew()
    {
        FlightCabinCrew fcc = new FlightCabinCrew();
        return View(fcc);
    }
```

Post action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddCrew(FlightCabinCrew fcc)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (A1Context db = new A1Context())
            {
                var data = from person in db.person
                           from flightcrew in db.flightcabincrew
                           from cabincrew in db.cabincrew
                           where flightcrew.cabinCrewId == cabincrew.person
                           where cabincrew.person == person.id
                           select person.name;

                ViewBag.list = new SelectList(data.ToList(), "id", "name");

                db.flightcabincrew.Add(fcc);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (A1Context db = new A1Context())
            {
                var data = from person in db.person
                           from flightcrew in db.flightcabincrew
                           from cabincrew in db.cabincrew
                           where flightcrew.cabinCrewId == cabincrew.person
                           where cabincrew.person == person.id
                           select person.name;

                ViewBag.list = new SelectList(data.ToList(), "name", "name");
                return View(fcc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cabinCrewId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.cabinCrewId, (SelectList)ViewBag.list)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cabinCrewId)
    </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the `SelectList` to `ViewBag` in the GET `AddCrew` method (as you have done in the POST method).  Note also you do not need to assign the `SelectList` in the POST method if `ModelState` is valid (your saving and then redirecting so its not necessary since your not returning the view)

Comment: Thanks that seems to have been my problem, I was wondering if you notice any issue in my query for data? Because I have: DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'person'. I have tried all of the possible options and none work.

Comment: Your query is only selecting one property (`select person.name;`) so `SelectList(data.ToList(), "name", "name");` is creating a `SelectList` based on `List<string>` and trying to set the value and text properties to `id` and `name` of `string`. You need to select the `id` and `name` properties

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and assitance! It works as it should.

Comment: Note also, in one case you had `SelectList(data.ToList(), "id", "name")` and the other `SelectList(data.ToList(), "name", "name")` - make sure they are both the same (I assume you want to bind the `id` property)