# MVC 4 Add error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I have had this error for over a day now and I really can't seem to fix it. I know there are a lot of questions on this topic online which I have read over and over and still haven't solved the issue.
I'm just learning MVC 4 so I'm extremely confused.
I get the error message:

The ViewData item that has the key 'cabinCrewId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

My Controller:

```
 public ActionResult AddCrew()
    {
        FlightCabinCrew fcc = new FlightCabinCrew();
        return View(fcc);
    }
```

Post action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddCrew(FlightCabinCrew fcc)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (A1Context db = new A1Context())
            {
                var data = from person in db.person
                           from flightcrew in db.flightcabincrew
                           from cabincrew in db.cabincrew
                           where flightcrew.cabinCrewId == cabincrew.person
                           where cabincrew.person == person.id
                           select person.name;

                ViewBag.list = new SelectList(data.ToList(), "id", "name");

                db.flightcabincrew.Add(fcc);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (A1Context db = new A1Context())
            {
                var data = from person in db.person
                           from flightcrew in db.flightcabincrew
                           from cabincrew in db.cabincrew
                           where flightcrew.cabinCrewId == cabincrew.person
                           where cabincrew.person == person.id
                           select person.name;

                ViewBag.list = new SelectList(data.ToList(), "name", "name");
                return View(fcc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cabinCrewId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.cabinCrewId, (SelectList)ViewBag.list)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cabinCrewId)
    </div>
```

Thanks

I know I need to assign the SelectList to ViewBag in the GET AddCrew method (as I have done in the POST method). but I do know what excatly is the GET method and what I put in it.

As requested  here is the person class

```
[Table("person")]
public class Person
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of `person` class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC 4 drop down box error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005982/mvc-4-drop-down-box-error)

Comment: @Leo Could you explain that answer please like what is the get method?

Comment: @user398239 I will in a minute

Comment: @Leo Ok I am waiting

Comment: @user398239 there you go

Comment: Note also you do not need to set the ViewBag property in the  `if (ModelState.IsValid) {...}` since your doing a redirect. Its only necessary in the `else` statement where you return the view.

Answer (score 0):

What that answer is saying is that you have two controllers. One that handles `http get` requests...

```
public ActionResult AddCrew(){...}
```

and another one that handles `http post` request...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddCrew(FlightCabinCrew fcc){...}
```

then you are rendering the same view for both controller methods. That view you are rendering expects a `ViewBag` object in order to be able to display items in a dropdown list...here...

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.cabinCrewId, (SelectList)ViewBag.list)
```

you are successfully setting the `ViewBag` object in the controllers action method that handles post requests...

```
ViewBag.list = new SelectList(data.ToList(), "id", "name");
```

but you need to do the same in the controller action method that handles the get request as well...that's what that answer says. The GET controller action method is the first one in your original question